# How to use RRD4J with mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, rrd4j

I want to use a MongoDB backend with RRD4J. Unfortunately, I can't find a fully working minimal example because of API changes and lacking documentation...

Comment: See if the test is helpful https://github.com/rrd4j/rrd4j/blob/master/src/test/java/org/rrd4j/core/RrdDbMongoDbTest.java

Answer (score 0):

@kevinadi suggestion solved my issue. I add that it needs the `mongodb-driver-legacy` because RRD4J uses the legacy APIs.